# jQuery :selected on multiple select selects only last option selected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to selected options on multiple select element. My code is working as the new class is being added, however, on submit, I am getting the value for the last option selected.

Basically making it normal select with multiple select attribute. The multiple select is working if I remove the entire code that adds the new class.

What I am doing wrong?

```js
var selects = $('#pwpusform select[multiple="multiple"]');

$(selects).each(function() {

  $(this).change(function() {
    var SelecteD = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected');
    $(SelecteD).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('optionselected');
    });
  }).change();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
For this HTML, I am getting the value of the option 5 which is selected at last.
<br/>
<select name="scattrmselect[]" class="pwpus-select-input" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="10" class="optionselected">Select 1</option>
  <option value="20">Select 2</option>
  <option value="30" selected="selected" class="optionselected">Select 3</option>
  <option value="40">Select 4</option>
  <option value="50" class="optionselected">Select 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did our answers help you to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$(".pwpus-select-input").change(function(){
       var options = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected');
       $(options).each(function(i,item){
          $(item).removeClass("optionselected").addClass("optionselected");
       });
 });
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8b6cLv44/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking. This works for me so have a look in your console

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pwpusform select[multiple="multiple"]').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      var sels = []; // debug
      $(this).find("option").removeClass("optionselected");
      var SelecteD = $(this).find('option:selected');
      $(SelecteD).each(function() {
        sels.push(this.value); // debug
        $(this).addClass('optionselected');
      });
      // debugging shows all selected options are available
      $("#sel").html(sels.join(",")+"<br/>"+$('#pwpusform').serialize());
    }).change();

  });
});
```

```css
.optionselected { text-decoration:underline }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<br/>
<form id="pwpusform">
  <select name="scattrmselect[]" class="pwpus-select-input" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="10" class="optionselected">Select 1</option>
    <option value="20">Select 2</option>
    <option value="30" selected="selected" class="optionselected">Select 3</option>
    <option value="40">Select 4</option>
    <option value="50" class="optionselected">Select 5</option>
  </select>
</form>
<span id="sel"></span>
```